# How to get row and column value from table layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I need to get the values of rows and columns from table layout when clicking an image, I have got the value of column but could not get row value and also I need to fling the row and column value but not image.

I need to get the value as (G,10) but am getting the value G only.

[image: I need to get the value as (G,10) but am getting the value G only]

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View view) {
n1=(TextView)tr1.getChildAt(1);
String k=n1.getText().toString();}
});
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you can use gridlayout or gridview for your layout.its very easy to implementation

Comment: May be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229945/getting-values-from-each-row-in-table-layout-in-android

Comment: Sorry,Am getting row value but i need to get both row and column value at the same time